# Ignite AffinityKeyMapped and AffinityKeyMapper

Tags: ignite

Using Ignite 2.6.0
What I would like to do: Use a class method to compute affinity key value for a cache. In other words for `IgniteCache<Key, Value>` I want to use `Key::someMethod` to compute the affinity key.

The default `GridCacheDefaultAffinityKeyMapper` class does not seem to support using class methods.

So I thought of using `CacheConfiguration::setAffinityMapper(AffinityKeyMapper)` with a custom class implementing `AffinityKeyMapper`. But `AffinityKeyMapper` is marked as deprecated.

If I am understanding things correctly, my two choices are
1. Compute the required affinity at object construction time and use `AffinityKeyMapped`
2. Ignore the deprecation warning and use `CacheConfiguration::setAffinityMapper(AffinityKeyMapper)`

Which of these is the right way, or is there a third way?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite stores data in binary format and do not deserialize objects on server side unless you ask explicitly about this in the code (for example, if you run a compute job and get something from a cache). As a matter of fact, in general case there are no key/value classes at all on server nodes, therefore there is no way to invoke a method or use `AffinityKeyMapper`. That's why it's deprecated.

I would recommend to predefine the affinity key value when you create the key object (i.e. go with option #1).